# Regex Optional Lookahead with non-greedy

Tags: node.js, regex

I am currently trying to create a regex that is able to parse the following lines of logs:

```
    [210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
    [210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_EXISTS /managed-element/fault-management/active-alarm/active-alarm-entries{oru oran-vendor-specific-alarm ORU[1]-ORU[1]/carrier0/antenna34/1004}[210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
    [210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_END_SESSION [210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
    [210616|13:46:38.361|00270] TRACE Established new CDB session to ConfD
```

By parsing in this case it would select the initial [time] followed by the description.

Matches:

```
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_EXISTS /managed-element/fault-management/active-alarm/active-alarm-entries{oru oran-vendor-specific-alarm ORU[1]-ORU[1]/carrier0/antenna34/1004}
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_END_SESSION [210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:38.361|00270] TRACE Established new CDB session to ConfD
```

[I started out with](https://regexr.com/611ma) `\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\].*` to select the initial part but I am having some trouble overcoming the variety in the logs:

1. There can be two logs per line
2. There can be a [#] in the log

I tried implementing a non-greedy per followed by positive look ahead in order to account for these issues, but now I am only able to select the first item and only if there are two items in a row.

https://regexr.com/611kh

```
\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\](.*?)(?=\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\])
```

I think ideally it would be my initial sequence followed by a non-greedy search followed by either a positive look ahead of my intial condition or an end line.

*For context, I am working on this for an Angular electron app in an Angular component.*

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spell out this pattern, use `\[\d{6}\|\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d+\|\d+\]`, see https://regex101.com/r/jHXpFr/1

Comment: Or I think you can use an alternation to assert the end of the string https://regex101.com/r/yoPm0f/1

Comment: Ah, if the goal is to split log entries on the same line or across lines, `(?!^)(?=\[\d{6}\|\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2}\.\d+\|\d+\])` can be used to regex-split the text. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHXpFr/2).

Comment: Thanks y'all. I think @Thefourthbird 's solution was what I was looking for. I should have better defined what I meant by parsing in this case.

Comment: You just need to add the language tag: what is your programming environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this pattern `\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\].*` the `.*` at the end will match the rest of the line

In this pattern `\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\](.*?)(?=\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\])` you match the beginning of the log with the square brackets and then capture as least as possible characters until the positive lookahead assertion at the end is true.

If the assertion is not true, the `.*?` non greedy part will suffice with matching 0 chars.

What you could do is add an alternation `|` which states matches as least as possible chars until you either encounter another log start, or the end of the string.

```
\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\](.*?)(?=\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yoPm0f/1)

If you want the 2 different parts, you can use 2 capture groups as well.

```
(\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\])\s*(.*?)(?=\[[^\[\|]*\|[^\]]*\]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/se71en/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to write the one regex that to rule them all, I would go for a simpler approach - string splitting.

First, split on a pattern that begins a new log entry (`/(?=\[\d+\|)/` works just fine), then slice the rest of the line at `]` and split once more at `|`:

```
var fileContents = `[210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_EXISTS /managed-element/fault-management/active-alarm/active-alarm-entries{oru oran-vendor-specific-alarm ORU[1]-ORU[1]/carrier0/antenna34/1004}
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:32.738|00017] TRACE CDB_END_SESSION [210616|13:46:32.738|00017]  --> CONFD_OK
[210616|13:46:38.361|00270] TRACE Established new CDB session to ConfD`

var lines = fileContents.split(/(?=\[\d+\|)/).map(line => {
    var pos = line.indexOf(']');
    return line.slice(1, pos).split('|').concat(line.slice(pos + 1).trim());
});

console.log(lines);
```

gives

```
[
  ["210616", "13:46:32.738", "00017", "--> CONFD_OK"],
  ["210616", "13:46:32.738", "00017", "TRACE CDB_EXISTS /managed-element/fault-management/active-alarm/active-alarm-entries{oru oran-vendor-specific-alarm ORU[1]-ORU[1]/carrier0/antenna34/1004}"],
  ["210616", "13:46:32.738", "00017", "--> CONFD_OK"],
  ["210616", "13:46:32.738", "00017", "TRACE CDB_END_SESSION"],
  ["210616", "13:46:32.738", "00017", "--> CONFD_OK"],
  ["210616", "13:46:38.361", "00270", "TRACE Established new CDB session to ConfD"]
]
```